# How to implement syntax highlight like SO?

Tags: syntax, syntax-highlighting

Best to be implemented in javascript.

And easy to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Overflow uses [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) from Google.

See [this question (on meta)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26649/commenting-one-line-of-visual-basic-code-comments-everything) for more discussion about this.

Comment: Prettify need class="prettyprint" to be add to <pre> or <code>,how to let wmd do this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611861/how-to-combine-wmd-and-prettify-like-so

Answer (score 1):

SO are using the [WMD editor](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/wmd-editor-reverse-engineered/).

Googling for "javascript syntax highlighter" also brings up a lot of useful stuff.

Comment: Prettify need class="prettyprint" to be add to <pre> or <code>,how to let wmd do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this very good code syntax highlighter project: [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter)